# How to get variables in script to work

Tags: ansible

I have the following Ansible script.

```
ansible localhost -m known_hosts -a "path=/home/vagrant/.ssh/known_hosts name=web key=\"{{ lookup('pipe', 'ssh-keyscan ' + item) }}\" state=present with_items={{hosts}}" --user vagrant -e "{hosts:[web, db]}"
```

Essentially it is meant to add a bunch of known hosts to the `known_hosts` file. I can't seem to get it to work with the array. Although I have managed to get it working for a single host.

```
ansible localhost -m known_hosts -a "path=/home/vagrant/.ssh/known_hosts name=web key=\"{{ lookup('pipe', 'ssh-keyscan ' + host) }}\" state=present" --user vagrant -e "host='web'"
```

Any ideas how I can get it working with the array?

Answer (score 1):

This might not be an answer to your question. More proposing an alternative.

Why are you trying to do it with Ansible? Ansible is a nice tool to get some tasks quickly done on remote hosts but I don't see how you could benefit from it in this situation.

Here's a one-liner that's even shorter than your Ansible command:

```
for HOST in web db; do if [ ! -n "$(grep "^$HOST " /home/vagrant/.ssh/known_hosts)" ]; then ssh-keyscan $HOST >> /home/vagrant/.ssh/known_hosts 2>/dev/null; fi; done
```

Comment: This was more of a learning exercise. I have managed to get the standard bash version working (yours is much more complete than mine).

Comment: I played around with it a bit. The correct way to pass the array seems to be `-e '{"hosts": ["web", "db"]}'` - though it appears like the loop is completely ignored: `One or more undefined variables: 'item' is undefined`